# How can I get and then add Staccato 222 font to my first website?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I want to make my first website. The logo of my company is written by Staccato 222 font. The only site I know to get fonts is google fonts, but Staccato is not available there. Could you recommend me a site where I can get the font Staccato 222? I want to add the font in a way everybody can see the same font i.e Stacatto 222. And how can I add it to my website?

Comment: You can purchase a webfont license at https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/staccato-222/.

Answer (score 0):

one of the reasons is that font maybe is licensed and not an open font.
I've found on this website some codesnippets.

https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/977ee109edb851f6c4a2c401445c74ee

You should habe your font in some of the following formats woff, ttf, svg, eot.
Than you can use css to use them.

```
@font-face {
src: url('your font') format('woff|ttf|svg|eot|…');
font-family: name;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck looking for it using its original name, **Mistral**.

In the 1980s, Bitstream started selling (authorized, from what I understand) digital versions of many classic fonts, using genericized names. Staccato 222 (Mistral) was one of them.